# Using requirejs With amdefine in node.js Producing Undefined Errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, amdefine

Running a simple server as:

```
requirejs = require("requirejs");
if (typeof define !== "function") {
    define = require("amdefine")(module);
}

requirejs.config({
    nodeRequire: require,
    baseUrl: __dirname + "/../.."
});

requirejs([
    "url"
], function (
    url
) {
    console.log(url.parse("http://user:pass@host.com:8080/p/a/t/h?query=string#hash"));
});
```

Produces the error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function at Url.parse (url.js:293:32)

However, if I remove the line `define = require("amdefine")(module);`, it all suddenly works fine. Since I would like to use `amdefine` in my project, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing the global variable `define`, you want to create a private variable of the same name in each file that you want to use it in. Instead of the line I had trouble with above, I should have put

```
if (typeof define !== 'function') { var define = require('amdefine')(module) }
```

Comment: can you post a full example?